# Trying to create a consistent ?-mark-inside-circle in CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a question-mark-inside-a-circle glyph using CSS. It should look like © basically.

```css
a::before {
    content: '?';
    font-size: 60%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.8ex;
    height: 1.8ex;
    border-radius: 1ex;
    color: blue;
    background: white;
    border: thin solid blue;
}

.infolink:hover::before {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="infolink" href="#">a link</a>
```

It's not bad on Firefox but the positioning of the question mark inside the circle is off-centre on Chrome (and I don't have IE to test but I'm assuming the worst).

I don't understand much about the nuances of fonts. Can this approach be made to work cross-platform or should I give up and use an image? I'm doing it this way to keep it scaled with the font.

Tweaking the settings as suggested so far is providing improvements only in select circumstances. There always seems to be some font sizes for which there is more than a rounding error (more than 1 pixel that is) of off-centreness either horizontally or vertically. The goal is to fit the border to the question mark, not fit the border to the square box which contains the question mark, as I suspect is happening.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hg7nP/).

Answer (score 10):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hg7nP/7/

Highlighting only the things I changed:

```
.infolink:before {
    font-size: 1.4ex;
    line-height: 1.8ex;
    border-radius: 1.2ex;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Regarding cross browser, it is working in all browsers except IE < 9 where `border-radius` won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the Abhitalk's answer and playing with it a bit, I've came up with a responsive approach, where the question mark and the circle are both scale in proportion to the base font size so you can easily set the size of the whole thing:

```
.infolink:after {
    content: '?';
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding: 0.13em 0.2em 0.09em 0.2em;
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<div class="infolink" style="font-size: 20px"></div>
```

If you see how this can be improved further, your comment is very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing `line-height:1;` Add that and it gets significantly better.

Personally I think it looks best with `font-size:50%`, but that's my opinion.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hg7nP/1/)

Comment: Thanks but if I play around with font sizes between the browsers, it still doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2):

Tested and is consistent in Chrome, Edge and Firefox (not tested IE).

```
.in-circle {
    display: block;
    background: #4444ff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

Apply to span element:

```
<span class="in-circle">?</span>
```

Solution sourced from: https://www.kith.org/jed/2020/04/15/two-ways-to-create-a-question-mark-in-circle-icon/

Alternatively, you could use a 3rd party library like Font Awesome, which has good cross-browser support.  Example here: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-question-circle

Comment: would you happen to know if Bulma css has an equivalent?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all; it just links to someone else's large, complicated, and minified stylesheet.

Comment: Well it did answer the question actually, but I agree using a 3rd party library isn't ideal.  I have updated my answer with a solution that excludes icon kits.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the line-height the same as the height of the element/pseudo-element.

```
line-height:1.8ex;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode characters to get a more concise solution. I used a question mark with Combining Enclosing Circle (U+20DD)

```css
.infolink::before {
    content: '?⃝';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
```